# What is Stack Overflow for Business?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-for-teams

Today I received an email that there is a new feature in Stack Overflow which is to improve our business. I have three main questions regarding new technology.

1. After reading all of the available content, I still don't know what Stack Overflow for Business is, or what type of companies are applicable to apply for this process.
2. There is no button or icon directing me to Stack Overflow for Business on my main page. Should I search for it in Google and log in whenever I want to address the business page, or is there a way I can directly access it from the main page?
3. Finally, what I want to know is how our data and private information will be secured. This thing should be serious, since this is an industry matter. If any of the information somehow leaked, the whole company could go down in a second.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing. At first I thought it was about the [Stack Overflow Business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com) (company) itself.

Comment: Me too. I think it is not suitable for small companies,

Comment: 4. How (if at all) is it related to [Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams)?

Comment: Seems to be no one knows since this is new technology.

Comment: Well at least the first impression it gives, is that it's differently branded teams.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## tl;dr

Stack Overflow for Business is ...

> for medium size businesses, typically from 40 to 1000-size tech team, [and] includes SSO and invoicing

to quote a senior sales executive at Stack Overflow for Business.

## details

I looked into this for the company I work for, and I received the following summary

> - You have SAML Single Sign On
> - NONE  of the information can be accessed by outside parties
> - SO for Business offers invoicing
> - You have Community Support to help success and usage
> - A Metrics Dashboard for the same purpose
> - You can assign a question to an individual OR a team, who will be notified to get to your answers quicker.
> - We fully integrate with Slack for updates too

Or from the [pricing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing),

> - All the features of Teams
> - Single sign-on (SSO), with SAML
> - Invoicing
> - Reporting and Analytics
> - Priority customer support
> - 99.5% uptime